# Send variables back to the constructor function (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, constructor

I hope I can ask this in a way that will make sense.

I'm not even sure if my title question is even what I need to do. So here goes nothing.

I'm attemping to create a game, basically i'm creating a 2D array which sets out a "map".

```
stage.addChild(new Grid5(stage,g1A,20,20));
```

So stage is my stageReference, g1A is my "grid1Array" and then the x and y.
Inside Grid5 i run a for loops to check the values of everything in my array, if it finds a 2 it creates a new "player"

Player then sets up on the map and adds keyboard event listeners, but in this game there are 2 or 3 maps, and therefore there are 2 or 3 players (1 on each map). This is all fine, it all works, but the players need to get to a certain spot on the map, and when they do i set a boolean to true. Each player has it's own boolean... What i need to do is find a way to check that all 3 players booleans are set to true to know that the game is finished.

So i have a function called `finished()`. Problem is, if i put it in the Player class, i can only check for it's own boolean, and that means when any 3 of the players gets to the end, the game would end. I thought i need to pass the result of the boolean back to the constructor and then do a loop through all the players, but then i'm not sure how to reference them as they were created in the grid class.

Answer (score 0):

**Fist way**

How stage add event listener(or you can add event listen on some parent of player).

```
stage.addEventListener("Finish", onPlayerFinish);

private function onPlayerFinish(e:Event):void {
    var player:Object = e.target;
}
```

how player dispatch event

```
player.dispatchEvent("Finish", true, false);
```

Assume you got a class named Main to control things.

1. When create a player, dispatch a event to inform that a new player had been add,
   in Main you can use a dictionary to keep players, like dic[player1] = false, dic[player2] = false, false means that player hasn't finished, true means finished.
2. when one player finisheds, you can also dispath a event to inform that the played has finished, and set dic[targetPlayer] = true. Then do a loop check with dic , the game finishes when all values are true.

A link about bubble
[bubble flow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e4f.html)

**Another way**

Use a global variable to save player state(not a elegant way). And you can update the global variable through a set function, then do check player state when the update function was called.

Comment: How do i dispatch an event from the Player class back to the Main class?

I can change the players finished bool to true but i'm not sure how to pass it back to the Main Class.

Comment: The simple way is add an event listener on stage, and the player dispatches the event ,the event's bubble should be true.